# Find list of closest points around a point in 3D space.

Tags: analytic-geometry, centroid

I have a list of points (x1,y1,z1) ...(xn,yn,zn).
I have another point in this space, (X,Y,Z).
I want to find a subset of the original points that form a boundary around (X,Y,Z).
Or in other words, a list of points that are closest to (X,Y,Z) in all directions.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Specify how far (a radius $R$) you want the subset of points to be from the given point, and go through the list of points one by one, calculating their distance from the given point, and select the ones that have a distance that is less than or equal to $R$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite easy if you have the right tools. As suggested by @Lexi, first choose the radius for the included points, call it $R_0$.

Next, establish a (column) vector $R$, as follows

$$
R=\sqrt{(X-x_n)^2+(Y-y_n)^2+(Z-z_n)^2}
$$

Then form the *logical* vector

$$
I=R\le R_0
$$

The subset of $I$ for which $I=1$ (logical!) will give the indices of the points which you desire.

This is much more efficient than the brute force method of comparing one point at a time, especially for very large $n$. The above equations are literally the two statements you need to do this in Matlab.